# How to make an object that goes off screen (while in full screen mode) to the left, reappear on the right (or vise versa)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, panel, game-physics

I am making a ping pong game, except instead of the ball bouncing off of the left and right walls, I want it to pass through them and reappear on the other side. I honestly just cant figure out how to do this correctly. Here is the line of code that I have so far:

```
                if (Ball.Right > Playground.Left)
            {
                Ball.Left = (Playground.Right + 26);
            }
            if (Ball.Left < Playground.Right)
            {
                Ball.Left = (Playground.Left - 1);
            }
```

Where as Ball would be the ping pong ball, Playground would be a panel that fills up the screen when game starts. Please help, I've been working on this game for a while, and just cant seem to figure this part out. +26 is to keep the ball from being in the way of the sides because of its width, that goes for the -1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

well you should just set the position after it goes offscreen.

```
if (Ball.Right > Playground.Right)
        {
            Ball.Left = 0;
        }
        if (Ball.Left < Playground.Left)
        {
            Ball.Left = Playground.Right - 1;
        }
```